# Are the websites for discussing specific textbooks?

Tags: book-recommendation

Is there any centralized forum for discussing particular textbooks?

Like the site would have a forum for textbook A, where posts would be like 'why did the author choose to present it this way, and not that?' 'Isn't Theorem 3.4 redundant?'

Ideally, the site would have special forums for basically all major math textbooks.

There have been many times I've wanted to ask an extremely specific question regarding a textbook (often times just ask for why an author chose to present something a certain way), but I have no idea where to do so.

I don't really know what tag to give this.

Comment: you can ask it here. I do not see what is the problem.